# Read Timeout TIdTCPClient

Tags: c++builder, indy10

Good day. I use the TIdTCPClient component to send requests to the server and read the response. I know the size of the response for certain requests, but not for others.

When I know the size of the response, then my data reading code looks like this:

```
IdTCPClient1->Socket->Write(requestBuffer);
IdTCPClient1->Socket->ReadBytes(answerBuffer, expectSize);
```

When the size of the response is not known to me, then I use this code:

```
IdTCPClient1->Socket->Write(requestBuffer);
IdTCPClient1->Socket->ReadBytes(answerBuffer, -1);
```

In both cases, I ran into problems.
In the first case, if the server does not return all the data (less than expectSize), then IdTCPClient1 will wait for ReadTimeout to finish, but there will be no data at all in the answerBuffer (even if the server sent something). Is this the logic behind TIdTCPClient? It is right?

In the second case, ReadTimeout does not work at all. That is, the ReadBytes function ends immediately and nothing is written to the answerBuffer, or several bytes from the server are written. However, I expected that since this function in this case does not know the number of bytes to read, it must wait for ReadTimeout and read the bytes, who came during this time. For the experiment, I inserted Sleep (500) between writing and reading, and then I read all the data that arrived.
May I ask you to answer why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

> Good day. I use the TIdTCPClient component to send requests to the server and read the response. I know the size of the response for certain requests, but not for others.

Why do you not know the size of all of the responses? What does your protocol actually look like? TCP is a byte stream, each message MUST be framed in such a way that a receiver can know where each message begins and ends in order to read the messages correctly and preserve the integrity of the stream. As such, messages MUST either include their size in their payload, or be uniquely delimited between messages. So, which is the case in your situation? It doesn't sound like you are handling either possibility.

> When the size of the response is not known to me, then I use this code:
>
> ```cpp
> IdTCPClient1->Socket->Write(requestBuffer);
> IdTCPClient1->Socket->ReadBytes(answerBuffer, -1);
> ```

When you set `AByteCount` to -1, that tells `ReadBytes()` to return whatever bytes are currently available in the `IOHandler`'s `InputBuffer`. If the `InputBuffer` is empty, `ReadBytes()` waits, up to the `ReadTimeout` interval, for at least 1 byte to arrive, and then it returns whatever bytes were actually received into the `InputBuffer`, up to the maximum specified by the `IOHandler`'s `RecvBufferSize`. So it may still take multiple reads to read an entire message in full.

In general, you should NEVER set `AByteCount` to -1 when dealing with an actual protocol. -1 is good to use only when proxying/streaming arbitrary data, where you don't care what the bytes actually are. Any other use require knowledge of the protocol's details of how messages are framed.

> In the first case, if the server does not return all the data (less than expectSize), then IdTCPClient1 will wait for ReadTimeout to finish, but there will be no data at all in the answerBuffer (even if the server sent something). Is this the logic behind TIdTCPClient? It is right?

Yes. When `AByteCount` is > 0, `ReadBytes()` waits for the specified number of bytes to be available in the `InputBuffer` before then extracting that many bytes into your output `TIdBytes`. Your `answerBuffer` will not be modified unless all of the requested bytes are available. If the `ReadTimeout` elapses, an `EIdReadTimeout` exception is raised, and your `answerBuffer` is left untouched.

If that is not the behavior you want, then consider using `ReadStream()` instead of `ReadBytes()`, using a `TIdMemoryBufferStream` or `TBytesStream` to read into.

> In the second case, ReadTimeout does not work at all. That is, the ReadBytes function ends immediately and nothing is written to the answerBuffer.

I have never heard of `ReadBytes()` not waiting for the `ReadTimeout`. What you describe should only happen if there are no bytes available in the `InputBuffer` and the `ReadTimeout` is set to some very small value, like 0 msecs.

> or several bytes from the server are written.

That is a perfectly reasonable outcome given you are asking `ReadBytes()` to read an arbitrary number of bytes between `1..RecvBufferSize`, inclusive, or read no bytes if the timeout elapses.

> However, I expected that since this function in this case does not know the number of bytes to read, it must wait for ReadTimeout and read the bytes, who came during this time.

That is how it should be working, yes. And how it has always worked. So I suggest you debug into `ReadBytes()` at runtime and find out why it is not working the way you are expecting. Also, make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy to begin with (or at least a version from the last few years).

Comment: Why do you not know the size of all of the responses?

Answer (score 0):

> Why do you not know the size of all of the responses?

Because, in fact, I'm doing a survey of an electronic device. This device has its own network IP address and port. So, the device can respond to the same request in different ways, depending on its status. Strictly speaking, there can be two answers to some queries and they have different lengths. It is in these cases, when reading, I specify AByteCount = -1 to read any device response.

> I have never heard of ReadBytes() not waiting for the ReadTimeout.

You're right! I was wrong. When specifying AByteCount = -1, I get one byte. As you said, if at least one byte arrives, it returns and ReadBytes() ends.

> Also, make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy to begin with (or at least a version from the last few years).

I am working with C++ Builder 10.3 Community Edition, Indy version 10.6.2.5366.